# scope element mapping configuration issue with IBM MobileFirst 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Env: IBM MobileFirst 8.0 , IBM DB2 10.5

i am facing issue with scope element mapping configuration. for the app in the MFP console , we configured the scope element mapping fro security checks for push notifications "push.mobileclient" and "access restricted". for some reason, this entries gets removed automatically frequently and app stops working.

anybody has any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is your issue is with only with scope mappings or even app is getting removed automatically from console ??

Comment: App remains in the console. only security tab and its configuration like scope mappings wipes off automatically.

Comment: What is the exact build level you are using?

Comment: IBM MFP Server Product version: 8.0.0.00-20160822-2140     
IBM DB2 : 10.5.300.125